# JS: Extract unique strings from multiple array elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

This is how my datastructure of an object array looks like:

```
const data = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    title: 'Sample Article',
    slug: 'sample-article',
    created: 1503160075
  },
  { 
    _id: 'ujJCBC2avK8QkR86t',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ'
    reference: [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ],
    timestamp: 1513054017
  },
  { 
    _id: 'KRhcfZSWFAawfxAsj',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ],
    timestamp: 1512864671
  }
]
```

Now I need to get all unique reference strings, which I tried to get doing this:

```
const result = data.filter(doc => doc.reference).map(doc => doc.reference)
```

But this gives me the result...

```
[ [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ], [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ] ]
```

...and I expected something like

```
[ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE', '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ]
```

I also need to eliminate duplicates (not shown in this sample data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *array.prototype.reduce* to concat reference arrays, *Set* to avoid duplicates and *spread operator* to convert *Set* back to array:

```js
var data = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    title: 'Sample Article',
    slug: 'sample-article',
    created: 1503160075
  },
  { 
    _id: 'ujJCBC2avK8QkR86t',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE', '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ],
    timestamp: 1513054017
  },
  { 
    _id: 'KRhcfZSWFAawfxAsj',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b', '8vtFExXqEF4HgDx2b' ],
    timestamp: 1512864671
  }
];

var result = [ ...new Set(data.reduce((m, doc) => m.concat(doc.reference || []), []))];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` instead of `map`

```
data.filter(doc => doc.reference).reduce( (a,b ) => a.concat( b.reference ),  [] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    title: 'Sample Article',
    slug: 'sample-article',
    created: 1503160075
  },
  { 
    _id: 'ujJCBC2avK8QkR86t',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ],
    timestamp: 1513054017
  },
  { 
    _id: 'KRhcfZSWFAawfxAsj',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ],
    timestamp: 1512864671
  }
];
var output = data.filter(doc => doc.reference).reduce( (a,b ) => a.concat(b.reference),  [] );

console.log( output );
```

Or **if** there is only one item in reference array

```
data.filter( doc => doc.reference ).map( a => a[0] );
```

**Edit**

> Now I need to get all unique reference strings, which I tried to get
>   doing this:

**If strings has to be unique then use this version**

```
data.reduce( function( a, b ) {
   if ( b.reference ) 
   {
       a = a.concat(b.filter( i => a.indexOf(i) == -1 ));
   }
   return a;
} , [] );
```

With arrow functions

```
data.reduce( ( a, b ) => ( b.reference ? a.concat( b.reference.filter( i => a.indexOf( i ) == -1 ) ) : a) , [] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    title: 'Sample Article',
    slug: 'sample-article',
    created: 1503160075
  },
  { 
    _id: 'ujJCBC2avK8QkR86t',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ],
    timestamp: 1513054017
  },
  { 
    _id: 'KRhcfZSWFAawfxAsj',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ],
    timestamp: 1512864671
  }
];
var output = data.reduce( ( a, b ) => ( b.reference ? a.concat( b.reference.filter( i => a.indexOf( i ) == -1 ) ) : a) , [] );
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Reduce is absolute overkill if OP needs to map properly. Plus way harder to read and understand.

Comment: @dfsq  *Plus way harder to read and understand* agreed, if you haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
let result = data.filter(doc => doc.reference).map(doc => doc.reference)[0]
result = [ ...result ]
```

The spread operator will spread it an array.

Comment: `result = [["9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE"], ["8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b"]]`

Comment: I have updated the answer kindly have a look at the result filtering. When you map the object simply get the first index every time the array performs a ```map```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map` to extract the reference then flatten the array:

```js
const data = [ 
  { 
    _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    title: 'Sample Article',
    slug: 'sample-article',
    created: 1503160075
  },
  { 
    _id: 'ujJCBC2avK8QkR86t',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '9Z7k2wAbXNXY2JWuE' ],
    timestamp: 1513054017
  },
  { 
    _id: 'KRhcfZSWFAawfxAsj',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum',
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    reference: [ '8vtFExXqEF4Hghx2b' ],
    timestamp: 1512864671
  }
]

console.log(...[].concat(...data.map(d => d.reference || [])));
```